# Delegates in Objective-C (iphone development) best practice

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So new to objective-c and iphone/ipad development. Trying to get my feet wet with a simple app to connect to one of our apis.

Right now I have a view with a user name and password input and button to submit. When it's clicked I grab those and try to authenticate against our server with a simple post call. I have that working using the NSURL stuff. I originally had it working by declaring the delegate methods for NSURLConnection in my view controller. Once I confirmed it was working properly I knew I needed to get that stuff out of there.

So I created a new class ApiLogin which has a method:

```
(void)authenticateWithUser:(NSString *)username andPassword:(NSString *)password
```

which does the post and then this object has the delegate methods declared and handles all that stuff. The next problem I ran in to was how to get any info back to the view controller. Since these were asynchronous calls I couldn't just have my method return data. So after some digging I tried out a solution that seemed to make sense. I created a custom delegate for my newly created class

```
(void)loginDidFinish:(NSString *)login
```

Which my view controller declares and uses. This worked perfectly.

So my question now is... am I going down a rabbit hole or is this good? I don't want to create a suite of classes or a class with children classes to handle server communication and data handling with a dozen of these delegate functions if that's bad form. Basically I'm asking, am I doing this right? Is there a better way? I feel like I've been given a new tool, and I see every problem as a chance to use that tool to solve it and don't want to make that mistake. Since I'm really new to iphone/ipad development and it's been a long time since I've done any serious C coding I feel a bit lost with some of this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find this link helpful, since it seems to be talking about a similar situation to yours where the author used delegates:

http://css.dzone.com/articles/do-not-publishcreating-your

Also, this Apple page might be a good read as well if you are curious about different ways in which objects can communicate with each other:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

The best way to be confident that you are using the right strategy, beyond simply asking other people for confirmation, is to make sure you understand the definition and purpose behind delegation, and then analyze your code from that perspective to see if its a good fit for what you are trying to do. Excerpt from Wikipedia:

> In software engineering, the
>   delegation pattern is a design pattern
>   in object-oriented programming where
>   an object, instead of performing one
>   of its stated tasks, delegates that
>   task to an associated helper object.
>   ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern )

Considering all that, I think you're on the right track with what you're currently doing.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Definitely sent me down the right path.

Answer (score 1):

That seems fine to me. The other solutions that come to mind would be to have your view controller observe a model object using Key-Value Observation and update accordingly, or to use an `NSNotification` when login is complete.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly reasonable for your view controller to be the delegate for items it is controlling. I would only break it out and make it it's own class if you needed to use the same methods in several view controllers, and the delegate methods were very complicated.

Comment: Well my issue was if I needed to make various calls to the server how to have the delegates handle the different calls properly. Seemed better to break it up into it's own object to handle all the server stuff.